# Is it possible to make the Tensorflow Lite model downloadable in Android?

Tags: android, performance, tensorflow, optimization, tensorflow-lite

I have a use-case where the APK size of my Android app is a very important parameter. Adding a TFLite model obviously increases this APK size, which is undesirable for me.

I have already quantized the model so that the APK size increase is minimal. However, I would like to make this model downloadable, rather than including it as an asset file.

Downloading the model after the app has been installed, is not as much of a problem for me.

Comment: I guess Android App Bundle may work in this case. https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/on-demand-delivery